# Adding Event Listener in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a wireframe of a Chrome Extension. In short, I want to make three separate screens and I'm going to have form elements on each one. For each, I just want to hide/show one of the other forms for now. So I'm adding a function to the first form, which should hide it. Console shows no errors, but nothing happens onClick:

Form:

```
<div id="step1" class="login">

    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <input type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" value="Log In">
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var el = document.getElementById('loginbtn');
if(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', login, false);
}

function login() {
document.getElementById('step1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Make sure the element with id `loginbtn` is added to the DOM before this statement `var el = document.getElementById('loginbtn');` is executed.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much.